# when looping through custom post data not appearing

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-field, loop, database

i have a loop that fetch custom post type from the database
now when i go to the page the data doesnt appear but when i refresh the page 2 times the data shows
here is the code:

```
    <div class="expertise-menu">

            <?php
    echo get_the_id();
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type'      => 'syllabus',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'related_expertise',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    'value'   =>  get_the_id() 
                )
            );

            $syllabus = new WP_Query($args);
            if($syllabus->have_posts()) {
                while( $syllabus->have_posts()) {
                            $syllabus->the_post(); 
                ?>
            <div class="expertise-menu__box" data-expertise="<?= get_field("related_expertise")[0]->post_name; ?>">
                <input type="checkbox" class="expertise-menu__input"
                    name="<?= get_field("related_expertise")[0]->post_name; ?>" id="<?= get_the_id(); ?>">
                <label for="<?= get_the_id(); ?>" class="expertise-menu__label">
                    <span class="svg-box">
                        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                            <path class="svg-rect"
                                d="M82,89H18c-3.87,0-7-3.13-7-7V18c0-3.87,3.13-7,7-7h64c3.87,0,7,3.13,7,7v64C89,85.87,85.87,89,82,89z" />
                            <polyline class="svg-check" points="25.5,53.5 39.5,67.5 72.5,34.5 " />
                        </svg>
                    </span>

                    <a href="<?= get_the_permalink(); ?>" class="expertise-menu__link">
                        <span class="expertise-menu__text"><?= get_the_title(); ?></span>
                        <span
                            class="expertise-menu__text expertise-menu__text--sub"><?= get_field('syllabus_code'); ?></span>
                    </a>
                    <span class="expertise-menu__arrow">
                        <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-chevron-right"
                            fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z" />
                        </svg>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <!-- Expertise Menu END -->
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution the problem was the "posts_per_page" it made my website crash on that specific section
and also in wp-config.php
added

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

and it solved my problem

Comment: Possibly due to `-1` pulling all the posts. This may be too much to handle for some server. It's almost always recommended to use a high upper limit such as `200` to avoid any type of crashing.

Comment: yes also that solved my problem thank you!